# Deserialization of ArrayList reads only one object

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I'd like to know why my program is reading only 1. element of written objects.
I have 2 classes:

```
public class Sheet implements Serializable{

int something1;
String something2;
}
```

next one:

```
public class Book implements Serializable{

ArrayList<Sheet> menu = new ArrayList<Sheet>();

public void newSheet(Sheet temp)
{ menu.add(temp);}

}
```

Saving Book (in class main Book is  static Book Libro = new Book();)

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream        ("libro.obiekt"));
                out.writeObject(Libro);
                out.close();
```

and reading:

```
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("libro.obiekt"));
        Libro = (Book) in.readObject();
        in.close();
```

When I do this, while having for example: 5 objects in ArrayList inside Libro, I can read only first one, while other 4 would be NULL objects....
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably have 5 elements in the list, but the 4 last ones being null, when serializing the book. I.e. the bug has 99.9999% chance of being in your code. With the code you posted, it's impossible to explain why. Create an SSCCE reproducing the problem, and post this SSCCE.

Comment: Well I can give you even entire code, but my 5 elements exists. I work with them, can print them, but when I save them and later load into my program I see only first one inicialized, while other are NULLs

Comment: Create the smallest complete program you could imagine that reproduces the problem, and post it here.

Comment: I've crated small project, but without using GUI, and it works...
I need to find why my mani Project sucks :-/

Comment: Congrats for having done that. It at least proves that the bug is in your code. Doing this effort often allows finding where the bug in the original code is. Good luck finding it. Use a debugger, and add a watch for the list of sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only read one object from file (serialized).

The reasons:

- Each time you write object to file. you are overwritting it. so you 
  can only get the last object written.
- even if you do set append to true

  ```
  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(file),true);
    //setting the append to true
  ```

deserializing will cause

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code
```

To overcome it:

**1. You could put all your objects in a list and write it as a whole (your arraylist).
serialize list of objects as a whole and deserialize it.**

**2. you can write each object in different file and read from it.**

Comment: The problem is in his code. He already said it in comments. He have a problem is his serialization code, it is not a Java API bug or anyhting else.

Comment: In the end I solved the problem- seems it works.
But I've only removed "static" from "static Book Libro = new Book();"
I totally dunno what's the difference, but seems it works O_O

Comment: @VardensArchangel wrote more than one and deserialized?

Comment: I've solved the problem: just before saving new data to file I read my previous file, add it to my list and then serialize entire list. If I want to keep order I: create new list, read file into it, add my "new" data, and then serialize.